# How can I convert a CIDR list to a IP range list in Python?

Tags: python, ip, converters, generator, cidr

Let's say I have a text file contains a bunch of cidr ip notations like this:

```
x.x.x.x/24
x.x.x.x/24
x.x.x.x/23
x.x.x.x/23
x.x.x.x/22
x.x.x.x/22
x.x.x.x/21
```

and goes on...

How can I convert these cidr notations to ip ranges in a new text file in python?

PS: This question is not same as my previous question. I asked all possible ips in that question. But in this question I ask "ip ranges"

Comment: @brbcoding not at all. this questions is: "cidr list to ip range list" and that question is: "generating all possible ips from a cidr list". "All possible ips" and "ip range" are different things.

Comment: Use the file reading from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641492/how-can-i-generate-all-possible-ips-from-a-list-of-ip-ranges-in-python