# python ipaddress module - IP address ranges that have an arbitrary start and end address

Tags: python, network-programming

I'm looking for a way to create a list of IP addresses with arbitrary start and end address in python `ipaddress` module.

> example: `ip_range = somefunc("192.168.1.1,192.168.1.10")`

from the documentation it appears that the module have a standard way of creating either single *`IPv4Address`* or CIDR *`IPv4Network`*, but not arbitrary list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate all possible IPs from a list of ip ranges in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641492/how-can-i-generate-all-possible-ips-from-a-list-of-ip-ranges-in-python)

Comment: Thanks @Peter.. 
hope there's nicer way than mentioned there.
So far https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_03.html#convert-an-ip-set-to-an-ip-range has native way of doing that. But it's outside of standard lib...