# Generate all numbers from 1.1.1.1 to 255.255.255.255

Tags: python

So I want to make a script in Python that generates all numbers from 1.1.1.1 to 255.255.255.255 (As Example, 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2, 1.1.1.3, ...)
How could I do something like that?
Thanks.

Comment: Please add your current approach as well

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Homework? (Which is fine, but all the more reason to ask questions about the problem, rather than ask us to do it for you.)

Comment: @Andrew Jaffe No, It's for a game

Comment: I believe `itertools` library is for you

Comment: @Abhinav Mathur So I would know how to generate the Numbers (With something like that print(range(1,255)), but I don't know how to do It with the Dots

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I generate all possible IPs from a list of ip ranges in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641492/how-can-i-generate-all-possible-ips-from-a-list-of-ip-ranges-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 3 has the `ipaddress` module:

```
import ipaddress
for address in range(0x01010101, 0xffffffff):
    print(ipaddress.IPv4Address(address))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `itertools.product`, you can go for:

```
from itertools import product

for p in product(range(256), repeat=4):
    print('.'.join(map(str, p)))
```

You could use `range(1, 256)` to exclude `0`, but `0`s are generally allowed in IP addresses. Since `256**4` is quite a large number, you might consider a lazy generator if early breaking is an option:

```
ips = ('.'.join(map(str, p)) for p in product(range(256), repeat=4))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for value in range(1, 256):
    for value2 in range(1, 256):
        for value3 in range(1, 256):
            for value4 in range(1, 256):
                print(f"{value}.{value2}{value3}.{value4}")
```

You need to use a nested for loop to iterate

Comment: This will not print 255. The max range should be 256.

Comment: Sorry about that. It is always the last value+1

Answer (score 0):

I tested two methods that the first one is much faster than the second one. You can check both at your own:

The faster method with `ipaddress` module:

```
import ipaddress
for ips in range(0x01010101, 0xffffffff):
    print(ipaddress.IPv4Address(ips))
```

The slower way is to use nested `for` loops, and I do not recommend as it's CPU-consuming, in fact it eats up resources:

```
for ip1 in range(1, 256):
    for ip2 in range(1, 256):
        for ip3 in range(1, 256):
            for ip4 in range(1, 256):
                ip = f'{ip1}.{ip2}.{ip3}.{ip4}\n'
                print(ip)
```